# In tkinter, python tells me that there is no option called sticky. How to fix it?

Tags: python, tkinter

In tkinter, I test the code when I write every quarter of it. I tested a quarter and python gave this error (the sticky option cannot be found for short and I edited the output a bit (eg: variable, text="sometext", path/to/file.pyw):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path/to/file.pyw", line 4, in <module> 
    variable = tk.Label(text="sometext", sticky="w")
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3148, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'label', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2572, in __init__
    self.tk.call(
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-sticky"
```

I'm using a windows laptop if you do need that info.

Comment: `sticky=` is an option that you use with the `.grid()` method, *not* the initial creation of the widget.

Comment: put that as an answer and I will gladly accept the answer. @jasonharper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are putting sticky in wrong place. You have to put `sticky` in `.grid(sticky=<>)`. Sticky is not an option of label but it helps to position the label and used in grid method positioning.

> sticky − What to do if the cell is larger than widget. By default, with sticky='', widget is centered in its cell. sticky may be the string concatenation of zero or more of N, E, S, W, NE, NW, SE, and SW, compass directions indicating the sides and corners of the cell to which widget sticks.

You can look [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_grid.htm) for more details and explanation about other options also.